# How to move a radial gradient (light spot) around on a background in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am developing an interactive touchscreen at my work which has four tiles on the main screen that look much like the Windows logo. At the moment they are different static colours and they don't look 'alive' and interactive. I want to make them glow or pulsate slightly in random areas and intervals. I thought about creating a white radial gradient and moving it randomly around the outside of each tile so the tile gradient changed, however, I am not sure how to code this in CSS.

I have tried to adapt some copied code that uses radial gradient animations that cycles through the complete hue gradient. The problem with this is I don't want to change the colours because they form the background for text (which can mess with the contrast). The changes can also be rather dramatic, going from a dark colour to very bright, which again messes with the text contrast.

I have already tried a linear gradient but am not happy with it as it is rather predictable and boring (the same gradient going back and forth).

What I am after ideally would be something like this:

[image]

Here is a code snippet of what is currently running:

```css
body,html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   height:100%;
  }
  
  .box{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
  }
  
  .gradDynamic{
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .gradDynamic:after, .gradDynamic:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    content:"";
    z-index:-1;
  }
  
  .gradDynamic:after{
    background:radial-gradient(circle,red,transparent);
    background-size:400%;
    animation:colorSpin 30s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .gradDynamic:before{
    background-color:yellow;
  }
  
  @keyframes colorSpin{
    25%{background-position:0 100%}
    50%{background-position:100% 100%}
    75%{background-position:100% 0}
    100%{filter:hue-rotate(360deg)}
  }
```

```html
<div class="box gradDynamic"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved the animated background with linear gradient background. Lets try this example and comment for further assistance.

```css
.gradient {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1846c4, #98b2ff, #1846c4);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    -webkit-animation: Animation 8s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: Animation 8s ease infinite;
    animation: Animation 8s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        background-position: 10% 0%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 91% 100%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 10% 0%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        background-position: 10% 0%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 91% 100%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 10% 0%;
    }
}

@keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        background-position: 10% 0%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 91% 100%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 10% 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

> Updated fiddle.

```css
#demo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3bd6f7 0%, #1539b9 100%);
    z-index: 2;
}

#demo:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
}


#demo::after {
    background-size: 400%;
    background-size: 400%;
    animation: colorSpin 40s linear infinite;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
}
#demo::after {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
}
@keyframes colorSpin {
    25% {
        background-position: 0 100%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 100%
    }
    75% {
        background-position: 100% 0
    }
    100% {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg)
    }
}

#demo::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #1539b9 0%, #1539b9 100%);
    opacity: 0;
    animation: bg 2800ms ease-in-out 3s infinite alternate-reverse;
    z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes bg {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Demo</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified in my post, I have already tried the linear gradient but it is rather predictable and a little boring (just going back and forth). That is why I was looking for something a little more randomised.

Comment: Can change the background color randomly?

Comment: Not really looking to change the colour so much as the gradient of a single colour i.e. blue to light blue

Comment: you want exactly like your reference picture right. But no gradient to be used

Comment: I would like it like the reference video, with the same gradient used in the video.

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere. Is it possible to keep the bottom the darker gradient (it is switching a little too much too quick at the moment)?

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Just one last thing, do you know how I get the content to fit the window?

Comment: The content will show inside the background only. you want to move the content where? share some screenshot.